# How to get a readable string from SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to get a human readable string from SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA() function.

My code is:

```
size_t strSize = RequiredSize / sizeof(wchar_t) + 1;
  wchar_t* DevName = new wchar_t[strSize];
  Name = new CHAR[strSize];


  Result = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA(InfoSet, &InfoData, SPDRP_DEVICEDESC, &Type, reinterpret_cast<PBYTE>(DevName), RequiredSize, &RequiredSize);
```

If Result is true, I want to convert the DevName value to a string using the following code:

```
size_t sizeCon;
    wcstombs_s(&sizeCon, Name, strSize, DevName, strSize);
```

But in "Name" I always get null and sizeCon is always '0'.

If I use a wide string (for example: wchar_t b[] = L"984567";) instead of the parameter DevName, I get a correct translation of the wide string to a character string.

In the [Documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertya) of SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA the PropertyBuffer parameter is described as a PBYTE. 
In all code examples, which I saw, the code examples uses a wchar variable. This wchar variable which will be casted to a PBYTE, like I do.

Now I am confused.

1. Why in the code examples is a wchar variable used, when the type of PropertyBuffer is PBYTE?
2. What is the correct type to use in SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA to get a string?
3. If I need to use a wchar variable, why the wcstombs_s function cannot convert the wchar variable to a char string?

Can someone help me to get the correct string from SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA?

Thank you.

Comment: There are two different functions: `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW` returns strings as `wchar_t` but `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA` (as you have used) returns them as `char`.

Comment: See [Unicode in the Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api), specifically the topic [Conventions for Function Prototypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes). You appear to be trying to solve a problem that only exists because you are avoiding the solution.

Comment: Thank you Adrian and IInspectable  for your help. I overseen the convention. Problem is solved.